# Combining vertical and horizontal parallax scrolling on the same webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

Does anyone know how to combine vertical and horizontal parallax scrolling on a single webpage, like in this interactive resume?

http://www.rleonardi.com/interactive-resume/

He seems to transition seamlessly from vertical scrolling, to horizontal scrolling, back to vertical scrolling, all with parallax effects. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I did notice a potential hint: at certain parts of the webpage, if you scroll backwards, the transition becomes very jarring rather than smooth.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dealt with parallax in a while, but when I did I used scroll magic.

here is a link to an example with what your looking for

[scrollmagic.io](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/expert/multiple_scroll_directions.html)